# Is there guidance around using too many directives with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is it bad practice, form-wise or performance-wise, to use directives for 'everything'? I'm beginning to see them as functions for rendering HTML, and like functions, they become useful when they are very discreet and combined.

However, I'm starting to get concerned that this might lead to poor performance or directive-overload. Here's an example of how I would like to use them - I am interested in feedback, especially about performance, etc.

```
  <!-- This could even be wrapped in a my-editing-area-navbar directive -->
  <my-navbard heading="{{pg.constants.navHeader}}">
    <my-jump-to-page></my-jump-to-page>

    <my-divider></my-divider>

    <my-undo></my-undo>
    <my-redo></my-redo>

    <my-divider></my-divider>

    <my-clear></my-clear>

    <my-accept-and-continue acceptFunction="pg.acceptAndContinue()"></my-accept-and-continue>

    <my-divider></my-divider>

    <my-reset-utility></my-reset-utility>
  </my-navbar>

  <my-left-column heading="{{pg.constants.leftColHeading}}">
    <my-preview-component></my-preview-component>

    <my-debug-utility ng-if="{{pg.showDebug}}"></my-debug-utility>
  </my-left-column>

  <my-main-content heading="{{pg.constants.mainHeading}}" subheading="{{pg.constants.mainSubheading}}">
      <my-message-viewer></my-message-viewer>

      <my-content-mainpulator>
        <my-content-frobber></my-content-frobber>

        <my-dohicky></my-dohicky>
      </my-content-mainpulator>
  </my-main-content>
</my-page>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, almost anything that's small, modular, and reusable should probably go in a directive. Keep it [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). If it's really specific to the controller/view, there's really no need to abstract it away into its own thing.

I can't say much about performance, but none of the directive heavy apps I've worked on have felt sluggish or anything. And I'm willing to trade what performance loss there might be for the encapsulation and reuse that directives provide.

I see directives just the same way as any other specialized html element (input boxes, text areas, etc), and use them the same way (this makes more sense when you know that angular is heading towards using the [Shadow DOM](http://oliversmith.io/technology/2012/05/19/inspecting-the-shadow-dom-in-google-chrome-inspector/)). Just make sure it's coded up well and you shouldn't see performance issues.